# Extract text file contents

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
edit 7
    set gateway 118.151.209.177
    set priority 1
    set device "port3"
    set comment "Yashtel"   

edit 56
    set dst 130.127.205.17 255.255.255.255
    set distance 5
    set device "Austin-Backup"
    set comment " www.scdhhs.gov"
edit 59
    set dst 10.100.100.0 255.255.252.0
    set distance 5
    set device "CityMD"
    set comment "Metronet"
```

The text file has above data i want to extract data from edit XX to set comment only if set device is "Austin-Backup". The file has 100's of edit commands

Output should should be like:

```
edit 56
    set dst 130.127.205.17 255.255.255.255
    set distance 5
    set device "Austin-Backup"
    set comment " www.scdhhs.gov"
```

Below is my code.
    string = 'set device'

```
word = '"Austin-Backup"'

import shutil

aa = open("result.txt", 'a')

with open('test.txt') as oldfile, open('cript.txt', 'r+') as new:
```

for line in oldfile:

```
    new.write(line)

    new.write('\n')

    if string not in line:
        pass
    elif string in line:

        if word in line:

            shutil.copy('cript.txt','result.txt')

        elif word not in line:

            print line

            new.seek(0)

            new.truncate()
```

After executing the code the cript.txt has only below line and result.txt is empty.

set comment "Metronet"

Comment: "It's not working" is not a valid problem statement. *What* isn't working? Please [edit] your question and post a [mcve] of your problem, including the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks.

Comment: For one thing, your indentation is incorrect on your post. Your `for` loop needs to be indented one level to be inside the `with` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you were trying to use `shutil` to do. If you just want to copy a few lines, you can store them in a buffer, and when you reach the next `"edit"` line, copy the contents of the buffer to the output file.

```
set_device = 'set device'
target = 'Austin-Backup'

with open('test.txt', 'r') as infile, open('result.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    buffer = []
    found = False
    for line in infile:
        if "edit" in line:
            # if buffer is worth saving
            if found:
                for line in buffer:
                    outfile.write(line)
            # reset buffer
            buffer = [line]
            found = False
        else:
            buffer.append(line)
        if set_device in line and target in line:
            found = True
```

Though there is likely a more efficient way of approaching the problem.

edit: I originally forgot to reset `found` to `False` after resetting `buffer`. Be sure you are using this latest version. Also `string` is generally a bad variable name because Python uses it internally, and because it isn't descriptive of its contents.

Comment: Omg...Super..Your code is perfect... I am new to python, only for networking stuffs i use python..Thanks a lot for the code... :)

Comment: @Bharath917 Sure. I made a couple small but important changes, be sure you use this latest version.

Comment: Sure..i did not know about buffering, i will learn that.. Once again thanks for the code..

Comment: In this context, it's not a feature of Python. A buffer is just a place to store data temporarily. In this case, it is a list of strings. You can call it anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution, just in case you were curious:

```
target = 'set device "Austin-Backup"'
buffer = []
with open('test.txt') as infile and open('crypt.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if not line.strip(): continue
        if line.startswith("edit"):
            outfile.write(''.join(buffer))
            buffer = [line]
            continue
        if not line.startswith('set device'):
            buffer.append(line)
        elif line.strip() == target:
            buffer.append(line)
        else:
            buffer = []
    outfile.write(''.join(buffer))
```